# get specific data filed from returned object in java

Tags: java, object

I have a homework to make a list of employees using Alist class and then find and print position of employee with minimum salary.
the problem is i must use getEntry() method in Alist class to check on the salary

```
public class Emp {

    public String name;
    public int number;
    public int salary;

    public Emp (String name, int number, int salary){
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + number + " " + salary;
    }
}

               //name number salary
Emp e = new Emp("ibra", 1234, 4500);
ListInterface list= new Alist();
list.add(e);
list.getEntry(0); // this will return -> ibra 1234 4500
```

Comment: Could you show us your Emp class source code?

Comment: Why not just have a `getSalary()` method in your `Emp` class. So it would be `e.getSalary();` or `list.getEntry(entryNumber).getSalary();`

Comment: Emp class source code http://goo.gl/M6ZDZx

Comment: it's a homework to make a list of employees using Alist class and then find and print position of employee with minimum salary

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is somewhat like your `Emp` class.

```
public class Emp {
    private String  name;
    private int     number;
    private int     salary;

    public Emp( String name, int number, int salary ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    /* some methods */
}
```

Make another method called (for example) `getSalary` like this

```
    public int getSalary( ) {
        return salary;
    }
```

Then use it as follows

```
Emp e = new Emp("aBc", 12415, 02125);
System.out.println(e.getSalary()); // will print 2125 because that's the salary
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify your `Emp` class to have it's own getter to return only the salary value.

Something like:

```
class Emp {
    private final String name;
    private final int empNumber;
    private final int salary;

    public Emp(String name, int empNumber, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.empNumber = empNumber;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    // ... etc ...
}
```

Now, to get the salary, just call `getSalary()` method. No string chopping required.

Now, using your list, you can get the salary values like:

```
int someSalary = list.getEntry(entryNumber).getSalary();
```

You can loop over the list and use a counter to get the different entries, etc...

Update:

If you *must* use the `toString()` method as provided in the `Emp` source, then you will need to `split()` that string by a delimiter. In your data's case, the space character `" "` is your delimiter.

To accomplish this, you may try something like:

```
System.out.println(list.getEntry(entryNumber).toString().split(" ")[2]);
```

This will print only the salary portion of the string `ibra 1234 4500`. The `split()` method will split the string on each space character, returning an array of 3 elements (0 through 2). Since the salary information is now at element 2 in the array, you can just use it like so `list.getEntry(entryNumber).toString().split(" ")[2]`.